# ionic 3 white spaces removed in item

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm quite new to Ionic.

I'm displaying a name in an item. Name is defined in my class as :

```
public user : String = "Jean       Richard";
```

And displayed using html :

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item>
      {{user}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

It's very simple, but I get this in my app :

[image]

There is no more space between 'Jean' and 'Richard'.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this isn't an `ionic` thing, but rather related to `html`. When rendering text, white-space will always be condensed to one space, unless explicitly stated otherwise - eg by using `&nbsp;` or some other method.